# Sumif not returning value

Tags: excel, sumifs

Hi I have two worksheets. Worksheet A looks like this:
Q1 is supposed to sum up values from worksheet B between 7/1/2015 and 9/30/2015

```
    Name |  Q1
Doe, John|  15
```

With more rows and columns added on.

Worksheet two looks like this

```
Date     | Doe, John | ...
7/1/2015 | 3         | ...
7/2/2015 | 3         | ...
7/3/2015 | 3         | ...
7/4/2015 | 3         | ...
...                  | ...
9/30/2015| 3         | ...
```

Where the date column is each date incremented by one day, and each row is with each name of a person.

I'm trying to sum up the numbers between two dates in worksheet A, and am trying the sumifs function, but it doesn't seem to work. The formula I have is:

```
=sumifs(Attendance!$B$2:$BS$552, Attendance!1:1, Summary!$A2, Attendance!A:A, and(Attendance!A:A>"7/1/2015", <"10/1/2015"))
```

**Basically what I'm trying to do is find out what column Doe, John is in and then sum up all the values in that specific column within a given boundary.** The only way that I know how to do it dynamically (without using macro) is to do offset, but that doesn't return a row name it would return a row index. It doesn't really help me to know that Doe, John is in index 2, because if I want to sum up all the values in the 2nd column I need to do something like sum(B:B), not sum(2:2)

Comment: You do not use AND that way just add a criterion: `=SUMIFS(Attendance!$B$2:$BS$552,Attendance!1:1,Summary!$A2,Attendance!A:A,">7/1/2015",Attendance!A:A," <10/1/2015")`

Comment: Hi using this formula =sumifs(Attendance!$B$2:$BS$552, Attendance!1:1,$A2, Attendance!A:A, >="7/1/2015", Attendance!A:A,<"10/1/2015") there is an error

Comment: The quotes need to surround the entire criterion, this `>="7/1/2015"` should be `">=7/1/2015"` and `<"10/1/2015"` should be `"<10/1/2015"`

Comment: =SUMIFS(Attendance!$B$2:$BS$552, Attendance!1:100,$A2, Attendance!A:A, ">=7/1/2015", Attendance!A:A,"<10/1/2015") returns the error 

#Value!

Comment: Why not just use a Pivot Table.  `Dates` ► Rows, Each `column Header` ► Values, and group the dates by quarters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$C$1=E3)*($A$2:$A$13<DATE(2015,10,1))*($A$2:$A$13>=DATE(2015,7,1))*B2:C13)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've heard about the sumproduct function being very useful but I've never had a chance to personally use it. Can you explain in english what is happening in the above formula? I tried to apply it as such:

=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$61=A2, Attendance!A2:A552>=date(2015,7,1) Attendance!A2:A552<date(2015,10,1),Attendance!$B$2:$BS$552)

and excel returns #value! I don't want to take up any more of your time, nor do I want you to answer the question for me.

Comment: If you look at mine I multiplied the booleans together.  You need to do this to turn the TRUE/FALSE into 1/0 respectively.  If you want to put the `,` between you will need to do some math for each to make the transition from Boolean to Bit. `=SUMPRODUCT(1*($A$2:$A$61=A2), 1*(Attendance!A2:A552>=date(2015,7,1)),1*(Attendance!A2:A552<date(2015,10,1)),Attendance!$B$2:$BS$552)`  That is messy and why i just multiplied them all together. @bdpolinsky

Comment: As an alternative, you could do this with a SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS(INDEX($B:$C,,MATCH(F3,$B$1:$C$1,0)),$A:$A,"<10/1/2015",$A:$A,">=7/1/2015")`